# Rails 3 table lock

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to lock database table. 
MySQL Example:

> LOCK TABLES users WRITE

..using some native ActiveRecord methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not supported by ActiveRecord, you will have to run it manually with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("LOCK TABLE users WRITE")
```

You may want to check out this [discussion at ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/180184) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass :lock => true to ActiveRecord::Base.find to obtain an exclusive lock on the selected rows

Pass :lock => 'some locking clause' to give a database-specific locking clause of your own such as ‘LOCK IN SHARE MODE’ or ‘FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html for details

Comment: The locking semantics in that link are about row level locking rather than entire tables.